# Using DataAnnotations to validate a textbox differently depending on a listbox selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a custom validation attribute that checks to make sure a birthday is at least 18 years in the past. I now have a requirement to change that to 19 years in the past if a seperate dropdown list has a specific state chosen.

Is it possible to change a custom validation on the fly? This is what I am currently using.

```
public class MyCustomDateAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
if (dt>= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18)){
return false;}
return true;
}}}
```

Somehow changing the -18 to -19.

I understand this is serverside only and that is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should override and implement

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
```

The validationContext parameter is the key that solves the problem.

The complete solution is at http://cncrrnt.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/custom-validationattribute-for-comparing-properties